# How to select the entire column starting from row 3 - vba

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, for-loop

Hey Guys here is my code it is working but instead of selecting the entire column I want to select all of the column buter after row 3, 
for example I want to select all of column b but after B3 
I hope that makes sense.

any ideas?

```
Sub HorizontalLoop()
Dim lCol As Long

Sheets("output").Select
For lCol = 1 To 100

Dim inputrange As String
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(lCol).Value) Then
inputrange = Cells(1, lCol).Value

Cells(1, lCol).EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("input").Select
ActiveSheet.range(inputrange).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("output").Select
End If
Next lCol
End Sub
```

Any help will be very much appreciated :) 
Thanks
H

Comment: This has been asked on SO many times. Or you can find it on google XD

Comment: I apologise if it's been asked so many times but when your new to VBA sometimes it's hard to understand in others peoples code!

Comment: So sorry for being annoying! But thanks everyone that's helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code (with your answer) a little cleaned up:

```
Sub HorizontalLoop()
Dim lCol As Long
Dim inputrange As String
With Sheets("output")
    For lCol = 1 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(1, lCol).Value) Then
            inputrange = .Cells(1, lCol).Value
            .Range(.Cells(3, lCol), .Cells(.Rows.Count, lCol)).Copy Sheets("input").Range(inputrange)
        End If
    Next lCol
End With
End Sub
```

Try to avoid using [`.Select` and `.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Also it is better to ensure proper parentage when using two sheets.  The With Block with its corresponding `.` allows this.

Answer (score 0):

Change A1 to your destination range

```
Sub test()

    Sheets("input").Range(Cells(3, "B") _
        , Cells(Sheets("input").Cells.Rows.Count, "B")).Copy Sheets("output").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@findwindow's right - has been asked so many times.

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("output").Cells(1, lcol).EntireColumn.Resize(Rows.Count - 3).Offset(3).Select`

There's no need to select the sheet though:

Create a new sheet and have that selected then use this code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("output").Cells(1, lcol).EntireColumn.Resize(Rows.Count - 3).Offset(3).Copy _
    Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input").Cells(4, 2)
```

It will copy from **output** to **input** without needing to have the sheet selected - just reference the sheets in your code.